# Random forest (or regression) when predictors are intervals

Tags: random-forest, markov-chain-montecarlo, expectation-maximization, measurement-error

I'm trying to fit a Random Forest model where the predictors are reported as an interval rather than a point estimate. The structure of each data point is a triplet $(\bar{y_i}, x_{i1}, x_{i2})$ where $x_{i1}<x_{i2}$, and where $\bar{y_i} = \frac{1}{x_{i2}-x_{i1}}\int_{x_i1}^{x_i2} f(x) dx$. That is, the $y_i$ is the average of the curve across the interval $[x_{i1}, x_{i2}]$. From the intermediate value theorem, I know there is a point $\bar{x_i} \in [x_{i1}, x_{i2}]$ such that $\bar{y_i} = f(\bar{x_i})$. What I want to estimate is this curve.

I've tried several approaches, such as EM-algorithm and hill-climbing, to try to iteratively estimate each $\bar{x_i} \in [x_{i1}, x_{i2}]$, then fit the random forest model $\bar{y_i}\sim f(\bar{x_i})$. For example, one approach I've tried is to first assign $x_i$ as the midpoint between $x_{i1}$ and $x_{i2}$. Then fit a random forest model to these data, and then use the resulting model to update $\bar{x_i}$ by finding the expected value for $x$ in the interval in $(x_{i1}, x_{i2})$, and then repeating. But at a certain point this just oscillates between different values (in part because of the stochastic nature of RF), and doesn't converge to a solution but just floats around slightly.

I feel like this must be a solved problem. Even ignoring the fact that $x_i$ is the expected value within the interval, are their standard approaches to fitting this sort of measurement error model, where the predictor is known to fall within some bound? I've been exploring MCMC approaches were I assign $x_i \sim Uniform(x_{i1}, x_{i2})$, but it's not straightforward how to nest this sort of Bayesian formulation within a machine learning setting.

Any thoughts or suggestions?